# How to zip archive individual sub folders

Tags: archive, automator

I have a main folder called "Test" under that I have around 100 sub folders starting from test 1, test 2 ..... test 100.

I am trying to create a work flow in Macautomator. But it puts all the 100 folders into one big archive file rather than creating 100 archive files with its original name in the mail Test folder. 
am I expecting too much from the automator. I would greatly appreciate your help .

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you out. Create the following Automator Workflow:

1. Ask for Finder Items

   - select folders
2. Set Value of Variable

   - variable name I put was "folder"
3. Get Folder Contents

   - select "Repeat for each subfolder"
4. Dispense Items Incrementally
5. Create Clean Archive

   - select "Deleting original files"
6. Loop

   - select "Loop Automatically" and "stop after 100 times" (or how many you want)

This should work. I tested it out.

Comment: It seems, that some of these Actions aren't available anymore in automator 2.4. and there's no way around the 'Run Shell Script' Action. This: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4513559 helped me out

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually my wife wrote shell script to do that, it worked like a charm. here it is #!/bin/bash
#FILES=Open Path/*
FILES=Destination Path/*
for f in $FILES
do
#  echo "Processing $f file..."
 echo $f 
#echo " AND "  ${f%.*}
ShortName=`echo $f | sed 's/ //g'`

echo "hello: " $ShortName

mv "$f" "$ShortName"

#zip -r $f.cbr $f 

done